# AngularJS Recursive Function on Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
 $scope.play = function (audio) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     api.play(audio).then(function () {
         deferred.resolve();
     }, function (err) {
         deferred.reject();
         console.log(err);
     });
     return deferred.promise;
 };
```

I have a array of `audio` that i use inside my controller and pass to `$scope.play`. However, using the below:

```
var playIndex = 0;
$scope.play(audios[playIndex]).then(function () {
    playIndex++;
    $scope.play(audios[playIndex]);
});
```

This works for the first two audios i have in the array of course since I am not checking the return of the second `.play`. How can i make this loop through all the audios array successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrapping existing promises in new deferrals is an anti-pattern. Your function should be `$scope.play = function (audio) { return api.play(audio); }`. That's it, really.

Answer (score 2):

You can name a function passed into `then` and invoke it from itself recursively:

```
var playIndex = 0;

$scope.play(audios[playIndex]).then(function next() {
    if (++playIndex < audios.length) {
        $scope.play(audios[playIndex]).then(next);
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3jx3eh8t/

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `poll` function that will call itself recursively when last audio promise get resolved. Pool function will call `$scope.play` which will increment `playIndex` on its success & then again call poll function which will look for the next audio to play on. You need to make sure by adding some condition before calling `poll(playIndex)` to get it called infinitely.

**Code**

```
(function poll(playIndex) {
    $scope.play(audios[playIndex]).then(function() {
        playIndex++;
        poll(playIndex);//here it should be call on some condition
    });
})(playIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate more as i'm not sure how to use this exactly. - Please note that the .play function takes `audios[index]` not just the index as you described.